# Prove that a ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

Let $(A, +, \cdot)$ be a ring with 8 elements. Prove that $(A, +, \cdot)$ is a field $\Leftrightarrow \forall x \in A\backslash \left\{0\right\} \exists \:a, b \in \left\{0, 1\right\}$ so that $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 1 = 0$.

I've tried to solve the $\Rightarrow$. This is what I did:

$A$ is a finite field $\Rightarrow$ $car(A) = p$, where $p$ is a prime number, but $p$ divides $8$, so $p = 2$.
$(A*, \cdot)$ is a group with 7 elements so $ord(x) = 7$ or $ord(x) = 1$.

$ord(x)  = 1$ $\Rightarrow x = 1 \Rightarrow \exists \:a=b=0$
$x \neq 1 \Rightarrow x^7 = 1 \Leftrightarrow (x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1) = 0 \Rightarrow a=1, b=0$ or $a=0, b=1$.

If you could help me to solve $\Leftarrow$ I would be truly grateful.

Comment: Do you already know that a polynomial in $\;F[x]\;,\;\;F\;$ a field,  always has some (or all) its roots in some extension field of $\;F\;$ ?

Comment: For the direction you worked you can use that $A$ is a vector space of dimension $3$ over the field of $2$ elements.

Comment: Bill's answer (+1) shows that all the non-zero elements of $A$ are invertible. You may want to add an argument as to why $A$ is a **commutative** ring. One way of seeing that is that the group $A^*$ is of order seven. Therefore it is cyclic, hence also commutative. It is also possible (and illuminating) to show that part using the fact that $A$ is vector space over $F=\Bbb{F}_2$. Then you would use the fact that obviously an element $x\in A\setminus F$ commutes with all polynomials in $x$ and coefficients from $F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ 1\, =\, x(-b-ax-x^2)\,\Rightarrow\,x$ is invertible.